# Rust rocket can't find the ignite function

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I try to use the `rocket::ignite()` function like [here](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#example). If I implement it in my code:

```
fn main() {
     rocket::ignite()
             .mount("/", routes![stream_controller::index])
             .mount("/events", routes![stream_controller::events])
             .launch();
}
```

the only result is this error:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `ignite` in crate `rocket`
  --> src/main.rs:10:13
   |
10 |     rocket::ignite()
   |             ^^^^^^ not found in `rocket`
```

Do I have to import an extra module that is missing? The example code does not show an extra module. Maybe the `ignite()` is deprecated? I only can use the `build()` function with `#[launch]`. But in many examples like `rocket-jwt` they use `ignite()`. I'm really confused about using the Manual Launching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most probably using Rocket `0.5`, but the example you referred to is for Rocket `0.4`. The `ignite()` function was removed in `0.5`.

See [`build()`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/fn.build.html) if you are targeting `0.5`. It's very similar to `ignite()` from `0.4`.

Keep in mind `0.5` is a major rewrite, where lots of things have changed, so always make sure you're looking at the right documentation (the version is a part of the URL). Also, currently `0.5` is still in `0.5.0-rc.2`, so you could expect some more things to change before it reaches a final state.